# Handling multiple expressions, and having those expressions in a DB

Tags: java, database

I'm having trouble asking the right question (of stack overflow or google) to find design patterns that likely already exist. I do have a solution that works, but seems overly complex. I'm looking for help on where to look for answers, or good examples of a similar problem. Like for example a GUI that handles multiple expressions in a query.

Here's an attempt at explaining the issue:

Ultimately, the problem being solved is the handling of multiple expressions, and multiple logic operations, and doing so by reading expressions back from a db.

I define an expression as having a left side, an operator, and right side. Like you would see in an statement:

```
(a==b)
```

Multiple expressions could therefor look like:

```
((a==b) && (c==d))
```

Or even

```
(((a==b) && (c==d)) || (e==f))
```

I can store the left, operator and right in the database easy enough:

```
EXPID   LEFTID  RIGHTID LEFT    OPERATOR    RIGHT
1                       'STATE' ==          'NH'
2                       'TYPE'  ==          'FUEL'
3       1       2               &&
```

Which would be read back as

```
((STATE==NH) && (TYPE==FUEL))
```

Perfect. Except it gets really complicated quickly. Take for example:

```
(ZIPCODE=='84770') AND (DEALER==NULL) AND (CAR_MODEL=='GTI') AND (CAR_BRAND=='VW') AND (LEGAL_OWNER==329778) AND (CAR_OWNER==459) AND ((STATE==UT) || (STATE==UT))
```

which would require something crazy like

```
EXPID   LEFTID  RIGHTID LEFT        OPERATOR    RIGHT
1                       ZIP         ==          84770
2                       DEALER      ==          NULL
3                       CAR_MODEL   ==          VW
4                       CAR_BRAND   ==          GTI
5                       STATE       ==          UT
6                       STATE       ==          NH
7       1       2                   &&
8       3       4                   &&
9       5       6                   ||
10      7       8                   &&
11      9       10                  &&
```

The problem get's worse with you want to map all this to a GUI.

Not sure if it is helpful to the question, but here is the output and code that handles the logic of multiple expressions:

```
Output:
$ javac Expression.java & java Expression
exp1: Expression [(A EQ A)]   evaluates to [true]
exp2: Expression [(C EQ D)]   evaluates to [false]
expOr (exp1 or exp2): Expression [((A EQ A) OR (C EQ D))]   evaluates to [true]
expAnd (exp1 and exp2): Expression [((A EQ A) AND (C EQ D))]   evaluates to [false]
complex (exp1 NEQ expAnd): Expression [((A EQ A) NEQ ((A EQ A) AND (C EQ D)))]   evaluates to [true]
n1: Expression [(5 EQ 5)]   evaluates to [true]
n2: Expression [(6 NEQ 5)]   evaluates to [true]
n3: Expression [(5 NEQ 5)]   evaluates to [false]
n4 (n1 EQ complex): Expression [((5 EQ 5) EQ ((A EQ A) NEQ ((A EQ A) AND (C EQ D))))]   evaluates to [true]



public class Expression
{
    enum Op {EQ,NEQ,OR,AND};
    Object left;
    Object right;
    Op op;

    public Expression(Object l,Op o,Object r)
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
        op = o;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        test("");
    }

    public void test(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(msg + ": Expression ["+toString()+"]   evaluates to ["+evaluate()+"]");
    }

    public boolean evaluate()
    {
        if(Op.EQ == op) return equals();
        if(Op.NEQ == op) return !equals();
        if(Op.OR == op) return or();
        if(Op.AND == op) return and();
        return false;
    }

    //logical equals of expression with passed in expression
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(o instanceof Expression)
        {
            Expression exp = (Expression)o;
            return evaluate() && exp.evaluate();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //compaire left and right for equality
    public boolean equals()
    {
        return left.equals(right);
    }

    //logical OR between left and right Expressions
    public boolean or()
    {
        if(left instanceof Expression && right instanceof Expression)
        {
            Expression expLeft = (Expression)left;
            Expression expRight = (Expression)right;
            return expLeft.evaluate() || expRight.evaluate();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //logical AND between left and right Expressions
    public boolean and()
    {
        if(left instanceof Expression && right instanceof Expression)
        {
            Expression expLeft = (Expression)left;
            Expression expRight = (Expression)right;
            return expLeft.evaluate() && expRight.evaluate();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("("+left.toString() + " " + op.toString() + " " + right.toString()+")");
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //compare some strings
        Expression exp1 = new Expression("A",Op.EQ,"A");
        exp1.test("exp1");

        Expression exp2 = new Expression("C",Op.EQ,"D");
        exp2.test("exp2");

        Expression expOr = new Expression(exp1,Op.OR,exp2);
        expOr.test("expOr (exp1 or exp2)");

        Expression expAnd = new Expression(exp1,Op.AND,exp2);
        expAnd.test("expAnd (exp1 and exp2)");

        Expression complex = new Expression(exp1,Op.NEQ,expAnd);
        complex.test("complex (exp1 NEQ expAnd)");


        //numeric comparisons
        Expression n1 = new Expression(5,Op.EQ,5);
        n1.test("n1");

        Expression n2 = new Expression(6,Op.NEQ,5);
        n2.test("n2");

        Expression n3 = new Expression(5,Op.NEQ,5);
        n3.test("n3");

        //numeric and strings
        Expression n4 = new Expression(n1,Op.EQ,complex);
        n4.test("n4 (n1 EQ complex)");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have discovered that relational databases were not designed to store nested data. Have you considered why you need all the sub expressions in a DB?

Comment: This doesn't look like the sort of data that is well modeled by a relational database -- I personally see no reason to normalize this data when it will obviously produce some real nasty queries for nested expressions.